# javascript - split string by custom separator and custom level

Tags: javascript, regex, split

#### my string contains ','

I have Piece of string can I have more power to split string,
What about RegEx.
My String:

```json
    a1{
        b1{
            c1="value",
            c2="value",
        },
    },
    a2{
        b1{
            c1="value",
            c2="value",
        },
        b2{
            c1="value",
            c2="value",
            c3="value",
        },
        b3{
            c1="value",
        }
    },
    a3{
        b1{
            c1="value",
        },
        b2{
            c1="value",
            c2="value",
        },
    },
```

can I split above string to groups by ','.
**BUT ONLY TOP LEVEL OF 'a'**

ex:

```js
aboveString.split(",");
/*[
  "a1{b1{c1=(value),c2=value,},b2{...etc",
  "a2{b1{c1=value,...etc",
  "a3...etc"
]*/
```

### [SOLVED]

OK, JSON PARSER do magic
but at question time i don't know, and i just know regex.
thanks for every answers

Comment: @mplungjan I mean Piece, I wrote fast

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
/,\s?(?=a\d+{)/
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zS2PTd/1)**

```js
const str = `a1{
    b1{
        c1=(value),
        c2=value,
    },
},
a2{
    b1{
        c1=value,
        c2=value,
    },
    b2{
        c1=value,
        c2=value,
        c3=value,
    },
    b3{
        c1=value,
    }
},
a3{
    b1{
        c1=value,
    },
    b2{
        c1=value,
        c2=value,
    },
},`

console.log(str.split(/,\s?(?=a\d+{)/))
```

Comment: thank you, **but if in single line it's not work correct `a1{ b1{  c1=(value),  c2=value, }, }, :obj-tyo{ b1{  c1=value,  c2=value, }, b2{  c1=value,  c2=value,  c3=value, }, b3{  c1=value, } }, @array{ b1{  c1=value, }, b2{  c1=value,  c2=value, }, },`, I edited to `/,\s*(?=[:@a-zA-Z0-9-]+{)/`

Comment: I edited for work if it's not in `a\d+` Form.

Comment: @NabilJaran because you mentioned `ONLY TOP LEVEL OF 'a'`. ok anyway

Answer (score -1):

You need to use some parser that counts the opening and closing brackets or use a regex engine that supports recursion. With the latter approach, you could use

```
a\d(\{(?:[^{}]+|(?1))+\})
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/jEh2TN/1/).